# New to JavaScript, Prompt & for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

How do i get a sum of a prompt input (example: i input 4 & get answer 10 (1+2+3+4) in a loop? or 10 and get 55 (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10)
Thanks

Comment: The formula `(x**2 + x)/2` will provide you with the sum from 1 up to and including x

Comment: @NickParsons I didn't even think about a simple formula. Way better than my approach.

Comment: @AshleyGrenon feel free to add it as an addition to your existing answer if you want

Answer (score 1):

To break the problem down, first you need to generate a range of numbers given your input.

You could create this a number of ways. A quick one liner is using the keys() method on an Array.

```
let range = [...Array(input).keys()];
```

The [keys() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) returns an iterator, so we'll use the spread operator to covert the object to a list. This will create a zero based list so you'll need to adjust the numbers by one.

```
let range = [...Array(input).keys()].map(x => x + 1);
```

Now, you need to sum up that range of numbers. You can use the [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the array to reduce it to a single value.

```
let sum = [...Array(input).keys()].map(x => x + 1).reduce((x, y) => x + y);
```

## Alternatively,

...and way more efficiently, as suggested by [@Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons) use the formula for calculating the sum of a sequence of numbers:

`(x**2 + x)/2`